# What is the fuel burn rate for climb of a C-130J Hercules?

Tags: aircraft-performance, fuel-consumption, c-130

I am trying to graph the payload range for a C-130J Hercules and I need an approximate value for fuel burn rate which I cannot seem to find online. Does anyone know approximately how much fuel a C-130J hercules would burn to climb 1000 ft?

This would be under atmospheric conditions and at standard speeds. The fuel burn rate of any other similar aircrafts is also appreciated. I am just looking for an educated estimation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rough estimation: for a mass of 60000 kg, the energy needed for that (1000 ft = 305 m) altitude change will be 60000 x 9,8 x 305 = 179 MJ. Jet fuel has a heating value of 44 MJ/kg, and if we assume a global conversion efficiency of –say– 7%, the fuel needed would be 179/(44 x 0,07) = 58 kg...

Comment: That's a great way of looking at it, thanks so much!